# I'm facing a problem with updating Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

I tried doing this

Optional command for temporary root privileges. So you won't need to keep typing sudo.

```
$ sudo su
```

enter password. (Note. This is not required, you can continue to use sudo, if you choose.)

First step, make sure your current Ubuntu Version's installed packages are up to date.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && dist-upgrade
```

Y when prompted

After that finishes...

```
$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Next up

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But it brings me this error 'The package 'linux-headers-3.13.0-generic' needs to be reintalled, but it is impossible to find some appropriate archives'

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it bring me this error  Invalid autoremove function

Answer (score 0):

#### Make your server system up-to-date

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

#### Reboot your system to finish installing updates:

`sudo reboot`

#### Install the update-manager-core package if it's not installed yet

`sudo apt install update-manager-core`

#### Edit this file, /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades using your favorite editor and set Prompt=lts:

`vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

[update_manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVR4.png)

#### After this, start the upgrade process

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

#### You have to reboot one last time to finish

`sudo init 6`